# How to get the property name used by outer-object for inner-object from the inner-object in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Okay, so code which is outside my control works like this:

```
Class A {

   function use_b($b_name) {
       $this ->  $b_name = new B();
   }
}

Class B {
   var $stuff;
}
```

So that the object of class B is inside of class A and class A will use a passed in name for the property name of the class B property.  Class B is totally unaware of the name it has been given and really doesn't need to know. But I need to know it in order to access class B from class A.

I do have enough control over the code that I can create a property for class B and set it to the name class A has given it, if that is possible. Then I can have class B pass it's name back to my function that needs to traverse class B (currently it returns only the outer object, so I have access to class B I just don't know the name it's been given.)

If that made no sense at all, please comment and let me know.

Comment: So you cant actually edit use_b method/edit anything in class A?

Answer (score 1):

Finding out the members of A that hold instances of B is not that hard. Try this code:

```
<?php
Class A {
   function use_b($b_name) {
       $this ->  $b_name = new B();
   }
}

Class B {
   var $stuff;
}

$a = new A();
$a->use_b('test');

foreach(get_object_vars($a) as $key=>$val)
    if(get_class($val) == 'B')
        echo $key . " is the member that holds an instance of B";
```

Comment: There is a set back to this, unfortunately.  For one (not to be picky, but...) I was hoping to avoid looping through the outer object.  The bigger problem is that use_b could be called several times.  I would have a short list to work from, but still nothing full-proof.

Comment: I'm not sure If I get your question right: You only have access to an object of A holding several instances of B in members, whose name you don't know. Even if B knew the name of the variable holding it, how exactly would you benefit from that?

Comment: Great question!  B has a method which, among other things, calls all custom functions registered to records of type A and passes those functions some sparse info as well as the entire A object. B also has some properties unique to its relationship with B that it stores as properties of B instead of passing them up to A (which makes sense, really, since A can have more than one B).  I need B to also pass in it's property name (if possible) so I can get those B-specific properties and respond accordingly in my function.  It would be too expensive, I think, to have B pass itself in the function..

Comment: Also, the name A uses isn't quite as arbitrary as I initially suggested. It matches up so something else in A that would be helpful to know, but the name in both places, while they do match, *is* arbitrary.  Basically the name represents a relationship between two objects, and B is the glue.  Since the two objects can have infinite relationships and since the naming of that relationship is arbitrary, I need to know which of the many possible relationships B is acting as the glue for.

Comment: I experimented a bit, but I don't believe there is a simple solution for this problem: When `$this ->  $b_name = new B();` is executed, e.g. the constructor of `B`, the variable `$b_name` does not yet exist, so it is impossible from inside of `B`s constructor to extract the name `$b_name`. Since you do not have access to the instance of `B` without knowing `$b_name`, there is no use of implementing all this as a method of `B`. If you want to try yourself again, have a look at PHPs `$GLOBALS` array, which holds all instances in the current scope. (At least that's what I think..)

Comment: Wow. Well you're my hero just for figuring that out.